# What do the letters ANT in ANT+ mean?

Tags: protocols, acronym, antplus

What do the letters ANT in ANT+ mean.

I understand the logic but not the "acronym", where do the words come from.

Reference: ANT+ (built on the base ANT protocol) defines device profiles that specify data formats, channel parameters and network keys. ANT+ is an interoperable wireless transfer capability that can be used with the basic ANT protocol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Garmin [training materials](https://www.digikey.fi/en/ptm/d/dynastream-innovations-inc/ant-protocol-basics/tutorial) it stands for "Adaptive
Network Topology".